# JavaScript: Get actual playback time of audio context?

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Pizzicato](https://alemangui.github.io/pizzicato/) for audio playing. If I call `sound.start(0, 10)` starting it at 10 seconds `sound.context.currentTime` doesn't reflect this, and in return makes my math wrong further down the line.

Is there a way to get the actual position its playing at? After manipulating it by pausing, and then replaying with offset? I'm doing it from a click event on a range slider.

Answer (score -1):

[HTMLMediaElement.currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)

> The HTMLMediaElement interface's currentTime property specifies the
> current playback time in seconds.
>
> ```
> const video = document.createElement('video');
> console.log(video.currentTime);
> ```

```js
var url = "https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.mp3";
document.querySelector("source").src = url;

document.querySelector("audio").addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.currentTime);
});
```

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I'm using Pizzicato library

Comment: `.currentTime` is there for your use...

Comment: It still counts up, or increments even when the video is paused, its inaccurate. It counts since the initial play.

Comment: `.currentTime` is accurate. See example above.